# Why can't i use a super class for a generic binded parameter

Tags: java, generics

Hey I have a question about generics on Java.

Basically I have two classes. One is the interface, and the other is the implementation of that interface.

Hand.java:

```
public interface Hand { 

   void move(double x, double y, double z, int rotaton);

}
```

RightHand.java:

```
public class RightHand implements Hand { 

   @Override
   public void move(double x, double y, double z, int rotaton) {
        ...Logic...
   }

}
```

What I'm trying to achieve (Failing);

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<RightHand> rightHands = new ArrayList<RightHand>();

    ...Add to rightHands logic...

    moveHandsRandomly(rightHands);
}

public static void moveHandsRandomly(List<Hand> hands) {
    ...Move Logic...
}
```

It's giving me a syntax error on moveHandsRandomly(rightHands). What i don't understand is, isn't RightHand essentially Hand? Why can't i use this logic?

Comment: It's possible that there's a syntax error in your `...Add to rightHands logic...`. Check the line or 2 above `moveHandsRandomly(rightHands);`

Comment: Nope :(. Try it yourself: http://pastebin.com/dTKAivcy